# Node.js environment variables on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

How can I set the environment variables that I'm using in my Node.js application on AWS EC2? I tried to export them inside the instance console but it didn't work. It's running on an ubuntu server 20.04 btw.(p.s. my application is coming from a git repository, so there isn't a .env file there).

Answer (score 0):

Manual Start:

```
Variable=ThisIsTheValue node index
```

---

System D:

```
Environment=Variable=ThisisTheValue
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /path/to/index.js
```

---